# Update envolvendo 3 tabelas

Tags: mysql

Tenho 3 tabelas:

```
TABELA A
ID   ID_TABELA_B
1    188
2    189   
3    190
4    200

TABELA B
ID    ID_TABELA_C
188   22
189   22   
190   22
200   23

TABELA C
ID   NAME
22   Gato
23   Cão
```

A tabela A está interligada a tabela B e a tabela B ligada a tabela C como podem ver através do campo FK_TABELA_[x].

É necessário fazer um update a tabela A em que o campo FK_TABELA_B fique igual ao maior ID da tabela B, porém se o campo FK_TABELA_C corresponder ao ID do 'Gato' na tabela C, ou seja 22.

Tenho que utilizar o termo 'Gato' porque em princípio não sei o ID do 'Gato', utilizei o 22 apenas para exemplo.

O resultado após a query seria:

```
TABELA A
ID   FK_TABELA_B
1    190
2    190   
3    190
4    200
```

O resultado acima é porque "190" é o maior ID na tabela B com o ID do "Gato" na tabela C.

Comment: É complicadito este...

Comment: @JorgeB. está faltando a relação com a tabela C. É necessário atualizar somente os registros da tabela A em que a tabela C seja igual a 'Gato', só que não tenho relação entre a tabela A e C e sim da tabela A com a B e a B com a C, como no exemplo que postei.

Comment: Eu percebi, já apaguei o comentário.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É isto que queres?

```
UPDATE A INNER JOIN B ON A.FK_TABELA_B = B.ID 
         INNER JOIN C ON B.FK_TABELA_C = C.ID 
         INNER JOIN (SELECT FK_TABELA_C, MAX( ID ) AS idMax
                     FROM B
                     GROUP BY FK_TABELA_C)
                    T ON C.ID = T.FK_TABELA_C
SET A.FK_TABELA_B = T.idMax;
```

Créditos para o [Joao Araujo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17576/joao-araujo) que resolveu isso em SQLServer.

Comment: Para ser só gato basta fazer um `WHERE C.NAME ='Gato'`

Comment: Boaaaaa! Funcionou perfeitamente com o where.

Answer (score 1):

Vou demonstrar de uma maneira mais simples sem esses *INNER JOIN, GROUP BY* etc..

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`tab_a` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`tab_b_id` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `test`.`tab_b` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`tab_c_id` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `test`.`tab_c` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `test`.`tab_c` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('22', 'GATO');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tab_c` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('23', 'CAO');

INSERT INTO `test`.`tab_b` (`id`, `tab_c_id`) VALUES ('188', '22');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tab_b` (`id`, `tab_c_id`) VALUES ('189', '22');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tab_b` (`id`, `tab_c_id`) VALUES ('190', '22');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tab_b` (`id`, `tab_c_id`) VALUES ('200', '23');

INSERT INTO `test`.`tab_a` (`tab_b_id`) VALUES ('188');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tab_a` (`tab_b_id`) VALUES ('189');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tab_a` (`tab_b_id`) VALUES ('190');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tab_a` (`tab_b_id`) VALUES ('200');
```

> O update para esse caso segue abaixo

```
update 
    tab_a a,
    tab_b b,
    tab_c c
    set a.tab_b_id=(select max(aux.id) from tab_b aux where aux.tab_c_id=c.id ) 
    where
        a.tab_b_id = b.id and
        b.tab_c_id = c.id and
        c.name = "GATO"
```